# Wrong parsing of xml file with pyton and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I tried to make two things.

1. I wanted to see the content of the  Tag.

Here is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import lxml

with open(r"C:\Users\myfile.xml", "r") as f:
    doc = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")


tags = doc.body.find_all("fr")
print(tags)
```

and this is the original file

```
<Main>
    <Header>
        <Version>1/Version>
    </Header>
    <Body>      
        <En>
        <Label>label1</Label>
            <Value>
                <Code>0</Code>
                <Label>label2</Label>
            </Value>
        </En>
        <Fr>
            <Label>label3</Label>
            <Ty>Ty1</Ty>
            <Id>0</Id>
            <BC>BC1</BC>
            <Def>
                <P1>0</P1>
            </Def>
            <fi>
                <Label>Label4</Label>
                <cmp>
                    <Ty>int</ty>
                    <fbs>1</fbs>
                    <bc>1</bc>
                    <q>1</q>
                    <o>1</o>
                 </cmp>
                <dis>
                    <ty>e</ty>
                    <el>t</el>
                    <p>
                        <p>1</p>
                        <c>1</c>
                        <l>1</l>
                    </p>
                    <g>
                        <m1>0</m1>
                        <m2>1</m2>
                    </g>
                 </dis>
            </fi>
        </fr>
```

**And here below is the result of the print** : it means that the (fr) tag contains nothing, which is wrong.

```
<fr/>
```

2. I simply tried to read from the original file and write in a new file
   This is the code

   ```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
   import lxml

   with open(r"C:\Users\myfile.xml", "r") as f:
       doc = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")
   f = open(r"C:\myotherfile.xml", "w")
   ```

   f.write(doc.prettify())
   f.close()

This is the result

```
    <main>
        <header>
            <version>
       1
      </version>
        </header>
        <body>
            <en>
                <label>
        label1
       </label>
                <value>
                    <code>
         0
        </code>
                    <label>
         label2
        </label>
                </value>                
            </enumerated>
    <fr/>
        <label>
  

     label3
      </label>
            <ty>
       int
      </ty>
            <id>
       0
      </id>
            <bc>
       95
      </bc>
            <def>
                <p1>
        0
       </p1>
            </def>
    <field>
            <label>
    label4
   </label>
            <cmp>
                <ty>
     int
    </ty>
                <fbs>
     24
    </fbs>
                <bc>
     8
    </bc>
                <q>
     0
    </q>
                <o>
     0
    </o>
            </cmp>
            <dis>
                <ty>
     e
    </ty>
                <el>
     t
    </el>
                <p>
                    <p>
      1
     </p>
                    <c/>
     1
     <l>
      1
     </l>
                </p>
                <g>
                    <m1>
      0
     </m1>
                    <m2>
      1
     </m2>
                </g>
            </dis>
        </fi>
```

The formatting issue is a known issue and i know how to fix it.

My problem is that the tag  doesn't contain anything anymore.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Upload a **valid** xml and explain what do you want to extract from it